# maven test fails with nullpointer but junit 5 ok

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, junit5

I'm having a strange problem with maven test with Junit 5.

I'd created the test suites with junit tools for each method, every test starts like this.

```
private Class2Test createTestSubject() {
        return new Class2Test();
    }

    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Class2Test testSubject;
        String result;

        // default test
        testSubject = createTestSubject();
        result = testSubject.getData();
        //testing, assert
}
```

The line
`result = testSubject.getData();`
returns a NullPointerException

When I execute the same test via eclipse finish ok. The surefire plugin are defined

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
            </dependency>                
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <entorno>${project.basedir}\resources\maqueta.properties</entorno>
                    <hibernate>${project.basedir}\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml</hibernate>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I'd tried to change the declaration of the object to dogde the nullpointer but it fails.

Class2Test() is the default constructor, doesn't requiere parameters or read files.

```
package test.com.my.myself;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.tools.configuration.base.MethodRef;
import com.my.myself.Class2Test;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;

@Generated(value = "org.junit-tools-1.1.0")
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class Tester1{


    private Class2Test createTestSubject() {
        return new Class2Test();
    }

    @DisplayName("TEST1")
    @MethodRef(name = "test1", signature = "()QString;")
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Class2Test testSubject;
        String result;

        // default test
        testSubject = createTestSubject();
        result = testSubject.test1();
    }
}
```

and the class to test

```
public class Class2Test{

    private Connection conn = new Connector();
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Class2Test.class);
    
    public String test1() {
         PrepareStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual");
         ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
         ...

         return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: whats in createTestSubject?? Let me guess - it reads some files?

Comment: It doesn't read files, configure parameters,  only create a dummy object to execute the method

Comment: You must show it, otherwise there is nothing anybody can do besides saying that testSubject is null.

Comment: The constructor of Class2Test is the default constructor

Comment: Remove the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency from surefire-plugin configuration. You have added the dependency to junit-jupiter as a dependency.  Also as already mentioned show a full test and furthermore what does that mean: `I'd created the test suites with junit tools for each method...`? Test suites are usually a bad idea... ?

Comment: Is that really your code?? Then NPE is not possible. Therfore you are hiding something.

Comment: You are mixing JUnit Jupiter and JUnit 4 `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` that is JUnit 4 ... Strongly recommend to read the JUnit Jupiter documentation https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with pom.xml the resources folder was wrong setted. :(

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.